# Php inserts first record only to MySQL from JSon file

Tags: php, json

I created the JSon file using the c# to export the selected records from the local MySQL database. The php code is used to insert the JSon file recods to the MySQL remote database. But the problem is, when I run the php code, it only inserts the first record from the JSon to the database rather than all records in the JSon file.

But I want to insert all the records to the database.

```
table : tbl_sales
the id field is AutoIncrement

+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| sale_item          | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sale_qty           | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| local_row_added_on | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_edited_on     | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id                 | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mytest"); // 1.
    $query = '';
    $table_data = '';
    $filename = "path.json";

    $data = file_get_contents($filename); // 2.
    $array = json_decode($data, true); // 3. 

    foreach($array as $row) // 4. 
    {
      $query .= "INSERT INTO tbl_sales(sale_item, sale_qty, local_row_added_on, last_edited_on) VALUES ('".$row["sale_item"]."', '".$row["sale_qty"]."', '".$row["local_row_added_on"]."', '".$row["last_edited_on"]."'); ";  // 5. 
      mysqli_query($connect, $query); // 6.         
    }

    echo "<h1>Successfully Imported JSON Data</h1>"; 
    // 1. Connect PHP to MySQL Database
    // 2. Read the JSON file in PHP
    // 3. Convert JSON String into PHP Array
    // 4. Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
    // 5. Make Multiple Insert Query 
    // 6. Run Mutliple Insert Query
?>
```

JSon file records(path.json) :

```
[
{
    "sale_item":"Sugar",
    "sale_qty":"5",
    "local_row_added_on":"2018-05-08 10:10:24",
    "last_edited_on":"2018-05-08 10:10:24",
    "id":"1"
},
{
    "sale_item":"Keyboard",
    "sale_qty":"2",
    "local_row_added_on":"2018-05-07 08:14:41",
    "last_edited_on":"2018-05-07 06:14:53",
    "id":"2"
},
{
    "sale_item":"Biscuit",
    "sale_qty":"3",
    "local_row_added_on":"2018-05-06 12:15:17",
    "last_edited_on":"2018-05-06 12:15:35",
    "id":"3"
},
{
    "sale_item":"Pen",
    "sale_qty":"25",
    "local_row_added_on":"2018-05-14 03:20:22",
    "last_edited_on":"2018-05-14 03:20:25",
    "id":"4"
},
{
    "sale_item":"Snacks",
    "sale_qty":"6",
    "local_row_added_on":"2018-05-07 05:30:40",
    "last_edited_on":"2018-05-16 05:30:40",
    "id":"5"}
]
```

Comment: Try echoing any value in your loop and check how many times the loop is running.

Comment: please can use var_dump($array); and give us the output of that ?

Comment: You're appending all queries to `$query` so it includes multiple queries. `mysqli_query()` only executes one query, so only the first is used. Instead of running the query on each iteration, you could build one multi-insert query: `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (row1val1, row1val2), (row2val1, row2val2), ...` and so on.

Comment: And you should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries like that, since it can lead to all sorts of escaping issues.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson: Thank you. I changed the `mysqli_connect` to `mysqli_multi_connect`.

Comment: There's no need for any multi query here. You can insert multiple rows in just one query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: `@Magnus Eriksson` How it is? single query does not work.

Comment: Sure it does, if you create it like: `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9), ... and so on`. You can find more info on the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html (second time I posted it)

Comment: Thank you so much, How can I change my above code as multiple insert query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, Your query is :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_sales(sale_item, sale_qty, local_row_added_on, 
last_edited_on) VALUES ('Sugar', '5', '2018-05-08 10:10:24', '2018-05-08 
10:10:24'); 
INSERT INTO tbl_sales(sale_item, sale_qty, local_row_added_on, 
last_edited_on) VALUES ('Keyboard', '2', '2018-05-07 08:14:41', '2018-05-07 
06:14:53'); 
INSERT INTO tbl_sales(sale_item, sale_qty, local_row_added_on, 
last_edited_on) VALUES ('Biscuit', '3', '2018-05-06 12:15:17', '2018-05-06 
12:15:35'); 
INSERT INTO tbl_sales(sale_item, sale_qty, local_row_added_on, 
last_edited_on) VALUES ('Pen', '25', '2018-05-14 03:20:22', '2018-05-14 
03:20:25'); 
INSERT INTO tbl_sales(sale_item, sale_qty, local_row_added_on, 
last_edited_on) VALUES ('Snacks', '6', '2018-05-07 05:30:40', '2018-05-16 
05:30:40');
```

and you should execute your query after the foreach loop:

```
$query='';
foreach($array as $row) // 4. 
{
  $query .= "INSERT INTO tbl_sales(sale_item, sale_qty, local_row_added_on, last_edited_on) VALUES ('".$row["sale_item"]."', '".$row["sale_qty"]."', '".$row["local_row_added_on"]."', '".$row["last_edited_on"]."'); ";  // 5. 

}
$result = mysqli_multi_query($connect,$query ) or die("Unable to insert: //6".mysql_error());
```

Comment: `mysqli_query()` doesn't execute multiple queries. You need to use `mysqli_multi_query()` for that. But as I pointed out in my comments to the original question, there's no need for a multi query since you can insert multiple rows in one single query.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback I have edited the code, you're totally right :).

Comment: @OmarAbuOmar Abu Omar Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

When building your query, you are using

```
$query .=
```

This adds the content onto the previous value.  The first time this is OK as there is no previous content.  Second time it adds a new insert onto the old one and will fail.  Remove the `.` to just set a new statement.

```
$query =
```

You should also look into prepared statements and bind variables, this helps protect from SQL injection and can aid in other ways.

Comment: I would also recommend unsing PDO instead of MYSQLI, but either way. PLEASE use a prepare statement for your own sake :)

Comment: @DomenikReitzner, prepared statements is the main point, the choice of API is not as important (IMHO).

Comment: Yes I do agree an that. PDO might help to migrate later on to a different type of db (maybe mssql or sqlite...)